# rust yew with wasm issue at deployment

Tags: nginx, rust, yew

This the first time deploying a wasm web app, I have deployed many go, php, python, perl, web apps before on nginx, apache etc.

- This is all working fine as dev on my PC and my Laptop.

-I am using rust yew and on the server
steps:

I git clone on the server.
run

```
trunk build --release
```

created the "dist" folder with the index.html the js files, css file and the wasm file etc.

I have other domains/apps on this server running so I add a new server block to nginx

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # IPv4
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # IPv6
    server_name portal.xxxxxx.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams-2048.pem;


    location / {
      root /home/portal/xxxx-portal/dist;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

of course I make sure the right permissions are on that folder.
I run it.
web works but I get a while page :( wasm is not loading

I open the page with "inspect" in the browser.
and says:

```
xxxxx/index.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”.
xxxxxxxx793a6701a28a04.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”)
The resource at “https://portal.xxxxxxxx.org/xxxxxxxxx793a6701a28a04_bg.wasm” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly. portal.xxxxxxxxxx.org
```

I have never seen this before, and I am new to Wasm apps and deployments, works right when I run it locally on port 3000

- I check nginx config seems OK, is serving.
- nginx -t reports all is ok.
- I check that it has the Wasm mime type, it does
- I went to the official doc, only says this: https://yew.rs/docs/more/deployment not much help.
- I can't find an example nginx config for the rust yew framework, so not sure if I need to add extra something since is a Wasm app...

Anyone familiar with rust yew can  tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you included `mime.types` in your `nginx.conf`? Does it contain the correct definitions for `text/css` and `text/javascript`?

Comment: Thank you, yeah for some reason nginx did not have the included mine.types under http block, weird... but is loading now, I still have one warning "Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content." any idea? also, if you can put your answers as answer reply below, I can select it as the correct one.